# Is $-\nabla f(x_1...x_n)$ the steepest descending direction of $f$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My understanding is that you get a vector that points in the steepest ascending direction of a function $f(x_1,...x_n)$ at point $\hat{X}$ by computing the gradient $\nabla f(X_1, ... X_n)$.

Does this mean that the negative gradient $-\nabla f(X_1,...X_n)$ is the steepest descending direction of the function $f$ at that point? It is obvious to me that this is the case for the derivative of one variable, but I am not certain it is analogous to the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the direction of steepest descent of $f$ at $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is the direction of steepest ascent of $-f$ at the same point.

Comment: Yes, this is sound! All terms of $\nabla f$ switch sign by switching the sign of $f$, so $-f$ must give us a gradient that is $-\nabla f$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: @BCI4evry1 Yes, that's right, $\nabla (-f) = - \nabla f$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, indeed recall that the directional derivative for every direction defined by a vector $\vec v$ by the doct product with the gradient, that is:

$$f_{\vec v}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla f \cdot \vec v=|\nabla f| \,|\vec v|\cos \theta$$

then the minimum is obtained when $\vec v$ is opposite to $\nabla f$ that is for $\theta=180°\implies \cos \theta=-1$.